# Objects Array - C++

Tags: c++

i am having a bit of trouble here. I dont know what i am doing wrong. My bike.cpp class is fine. But i think the problem is with bike_shed class, i am having problem with the "park" and "checklegal" methods. we are asked to do something like this: " The class BikeShed with a private array of 10 default constructed Bike objects. The class should have the following public methods:

- A default constructor BikeShed() as supplied by the compiler.
- A function bool park( const Bike& ) which adds a bike to an available
  spot and returns true. If the BikeShed is full, the function returns 
  false.
- A function Bike remove( const string&int ) that removes and returns
  the first bike with an owner of the given name. If such a bike is not
  found, the function returns a bike "None".
- A function bool    checkLegal() that will return true if all bikes
  owned by other than    "None" are legal. If a bike is found illegal
  print a message printing    the bike.
- A function void print( ) that    prints all the bikes with    owners
  other than "None"."

here is my code:

here is bike_shed.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bike_shed.h"
#include "Bike.h"

using namespace std;

void bike_shed::print(){

    cout<< "Bike: " << sizeof(Bike) <<endl;

}

bool bike_shed::checkLegal() {

    Bike bike1;

    if(bike1.getOwner() == "None"){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}

//Bike bike_shed::remove( const string&, int ) {
//
//
//}

bool bike_shed::park( const Bike& ) {

        if (sizeof(Bike) > 10) {
            return false;
        }

}
```

and here is the Bike.cpp file

```
#include "Bike.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void Bike::setNLight(int _light) {
    d_nLight = _light;
}

void Bike::setBell(bool _bell) {
d_bell = _bell;
}

void Bike::setOwner(string _owner) {
d_owner = _owner;
}

void Bike::setReflector(bool _reflector) {
    d_reflector = _reflector;
}

int Bike::getNLight() {
    return d_nLight;
}

string Bike::getOwner() {
    return d_owner;
}

bool Bike:: hasReflector() {

    if (d_reflector == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }
}

    bool Bike:: hasBell(){

        if(d_bell == true) {
            return  true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

bool Bike::isLegal() {
    if (d_nLight >= 1 && d_reflector && d_bell) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void Bike::print() {
    cout << "Owner: " << d_owner << " Color: " << d_color.Red << " " << d_color.Green << " " << d_color.Blue
    << " " << " Lights: " << d_nLight << " Bell: " << d_bell << " Reflector: " <<d_reflector << endl;
}

Bike::Bike(string name, Color color){
    d_owner = name;
    d_color = color;
}
```

and here is the bike_shed.h file

```
#include "Bike.h"

class bike_shed {

public:

bike_shed();
bool park( const Bike& );
Bike remove( const string&, int );
bool checkLegal();
void print();


public:
Bike bike[10];};
```

i would really appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you :)

Comment: You might want to clarify the signature of the remove method. What is the `int` for? In your description at the top, you did not place a comma between the `string` and the `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following block of code,

```
    if (sizeof(Bike) > 10) {
        return false;
    }
```

I am guessing that you are trying to make sure that you don't allow parking of more than 10 bikes in the shed.

In order to do that, you need to have a member variable in `park_shed` to indicate the number of bikes parked in the shed. Then, you can use:

```
bool bike_shed::park( const Bike& bike)
{
   if ( number_of_parked_bikes < 10 )
   {
      bikes[number_of_parked_bikes] = bike;
      ++number_of_parked_bikes;
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      retun false;
   }
}
```

Make sure to initialize `number_of_parked_bikes` to zero in the constructor.

The `checkLegal` function would be something like:

```
// Make it a `const` member function since it does not
// change anything in bike_shed.
bool bike_shed::checkLegal() const
{
   bool isLegal = true;
   for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_parked_bikes; ++i )
   {
      if ( bikes[i].getOwner() == "None" )
      {
         // No need to check whether this bike is legar or not.
      }
      else if (!bikes[i].isLegal() )
      {
         isLegal = false;
         cout << "Illegal bike found.\n";
         bikes[i].print();
      }
   }

   return isLegal;
}
```

Comment: When removing a bike, you may also need to compact the array. The simple way to do it is swap the last element into the position of the deleted element (or do nothing if the deleted element was the last element). This is due to the implicit assumption in this answer that `bikes[number_of_parked_bikes]` is where new bikes are always added, which is not such a bad assumption.

Comment: What do you mean to have a member variable in pard_shed. do i just do, Bike park_shed; ?

Comment: In the class `park_shed`, add a line `int number_of_parked_bikes;` right after `Bike bike[10];`.

Comment: @RSahu and for the park method the "bikes" that you added to, it says the variable doesnt exists, so do i do something like this. Bike bikes; ? right before the if statement.

Comment: That was an error on my part. I assumed that the array variable was named `bikes`, like `Bike bikes[10];`.

Comment: @RSahu no worries man thanks :) bro can you look at my checkLegal method too? idk what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @RSahu the gentleman at the bottom, he suggested an answer, but he added a parameter to it. I dont think we should add one.

Comment: if i do something like that, i am getting an error saying "non-constant function 'getOwner' is called on constant function.

Comment: It will be good for you get in the habit of making all the member functions that don't modify an object to be `const` member functions.

Comment: @RSahu yeah you are right. the prof was actually talking about this today. but we are asked not to. prof is strict :p

Comment: so i fixed the const part, its good now. but for the main method i just do like: Color acol;
    acol.Red = 0.0;
    acol.Green = 0.5;
    acol.Blue = 0.7;

    Bike bike("Hamid", acol);

    bike.print();

    bike_shed test;

    test.park(bike);

    test.print(); right?

Answer (score 0):

In method checkLegal() you may want to check whether a given Bike is valid or not before insertion, so you can write something like :

```
bool bike_shed::checkLegal(const Bike &bike1) {

    if(bike1.getOwner() == "None"){  // or maybe bike1.isLegal()
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also if you want to print all bikes in bike_shed you might want to write something like :

```
void bike_shed::print(){

    for (int iBike = 0; iBike < nbBikes < iBike++)
        bike[iBike].print();

}
```

Comment: why did you add Const Bike &bike1 to the checkLegal method? it shouldnt take any parameters.

Comment: and also the variable nbBikes, what is that? is it of type Bike or bike_shed? Like, Bike nbBikes; or bike_shed nbBikes; ?

Comment: if i do something like that for checkLegal, i am getting an error saying "non-constant function 'getOwner' is called on constant function.